# Group dataframe by the hour of the day in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

this is my first time here.
My aim is to group the data by the hour of the day, sum the 'flow' column for the rows of each group and divide it by 60.
But i'm having some difficulty about group my data by the hour of the day.

This is how my dataframe( over 150.000 rows) looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/i51V2.png

I tried by using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.read_csv('staz_1.csv')
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
group = df.groupby(df.timestamp.dt.hour)['flow'].sum()/60
```

But i obtained data grouped only by hours without the distinction of the day, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBUZq.png

So my question: Is possible to group data by each hour of each day to have a rapresentation like this?

```
   timestamp               flow
1  2020-03-30 06:00:00     708.0
2  2020-03-30 07:00:00     862.0 
3  2020-03-30 08:00:00     858.0
4  2020-03-30 09:00:00     840.0
5  2020-03-30 10:00:00     835.0
...
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have columns within date time forms, you can make use of pandas functions to help group data more semantically using the `.resample()` method.

You can group by [any time value](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html), like `days` or `hours`, so you don't have to remember more complex syntax like `df.groupby([df.timestamp.dt.date, df.timestamp.dt.hour])`. All you need is `df.resample("H")` (if your index is already in time date).

Below is if you don't have your index as a time date type. You'll need to first specify what you're aggregating on, which in this case is the `timestamp` column.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Time is a column and created data per minute
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': pd.date_range('2020-03-30', periods=300, freq='T'),
                   'flow': np.random.randint(60, 1000, 300)})
df
#               timestamp  flow
# 0   2020-03-30 00:00:00   488
# 1   2020-03-30 00:01:00   996
# 2   2020-03-30 00:02:00   437
# 3   2020-03-30 00:03:00   599
# 4   2020-03-30 00:04:00   405
# ..                  ...   ...
# 295 2020-03-30 04:55:00   302
# 296 2020-03-30 04:56:00   425
# 297 2020-03-30 04:57:00   404
# 298 2020-03-30 04:58:00   987
# 299 2020-03-30 04:59:00   135
# 
# [300 rows x 2 columns]

# Returns data frame
df.resample("H", on='timestamp').sum() / 60
#                            flow
# timestamp                      
# 2020-03-30 00:00:00  523.350000
# 2020-03-30 01:00:00  548.033333
# 2020-03-30 02:00:00  516.466667
# 2020-03-30 03:00:00  425.533333
# 2020-03-30 04:00:00  490.416667
```

Below is if you do have it as an index.

```py
# Index is time
df_idx = pd.DataFrame({'flow': np.random.randint(60, 1000, 300)},
                      index=pd.date_range('2020-03-30', periods=300, freq='T'))
df_idx
#                      flow
# 2020-03-30 00:00:00   532
# 2020-03-30 00:01:00   341
# 2020-03-30 00:02:00   964
# 2020-03-30 00:03:00   885
# 2020-03-30 00:04:00   186
# ...                   ...
# 2020-03-30 04:55:00   996
# 2020-03-30 04:56:00   946
# 2020-03-30 04:57:00   510
# 2020-03-30 04:58:00   564
# 2020-03-30 04:59:00   918
# 
# [300 rows x 1 columns]

# Returns a series
df_idx['flow'].resample('H').sum() / 60
# 2020-03-30 00:00:00    569.516667
# 2020-03-30 01:00:00    548.050000
# 2020-03-30 02:00:00    505.283333
# 2020-03-30 03:00:00    530.566667
# 2020-03-30 04:00:00    522.383333
# Freq: H, Name: flow, dtype: float64
```

The pandas documentation page on the `.resample()` method is quite useful as well https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas.DataFrame.resample.

Comment: Why do you need to divide by 60?

Comment: @YogeshRiyat We divide by 60 because we're resampling from the minute level up to the hour level. I generated random data at the per minute level. But when we resample, we're resampling up to the hour. There are 60 minutes in an hour, so we have to divide by 60 after summing all the per minute values to get the average amount per hour. You can leave it without dividing by 60 if you want the total amount during that time period.

Answer (score 2):

Use [df.reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas-dataframe-reset-index)

```
df = df.groupby(df.timestamp.dt.hour)['flow'].sum().reset_index()
df['flow'] = df['flow']/60
```

Comment: So neat!  congrats for the answer

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, it sounds to me like you have data from multiple hours and multiple dates and want each group to be a particular hour on a particular day? If that's the case, then you'll want to use two columns in your groupby. Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.read_csv('staz_1.csv')
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
group = df.groupby([df.timestamp.dt.date, df.timestamp.dt.hour])['flow'].sum()/60
```

Be aware that this will created a multi-index in the resulting grouped dataframe, which can be tricky to deal with. You can get rid of that by using `.reset_index()` on `group`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i tried your tip and it's fine, but i've obtain two timestamp column: the first with the date ( year-month-day) and the second with the hour( only an integer number). It's possible to have only one timestamp column in the following format: year-month-day  hour-minut-second ?

Comment: How about grouping by `df.timestamp.dt.floor('h')` instead? Like this:

`group = df.groupby(df.timestamp.dt.floor('h'))['flow'].sum()/60`